# Why I get 'No such file or directory' error

Tags: groovy, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am new in Gradle. I trie to read existing files' content & write their content to a new file which is not existing in file system yet.

```
File existingFile1 = new File(path1);
File existingFile2 = new File(path2);
File newFile = new File(path3);

newFile.withWriter{ w ->
    [existingFile1, existingFile2].each{ f ->
      new File(f).withReader { r ->
         w << r << '\n'
      }
}
```

But, my gradle complains that **No such file or directory** `path3`. Why it complains path3? I mean of course file of path3 is not existing yet, I am writing the code to create this file. Any one can explain to me why my gradle complains it?

I am writing my gradle build script in Android studio & I am using Gradle V2.2.1

Answer (score 5):

you will also have to create the path the file will end up. if the parent directory is not there yet, your creation fails.  e.g:

```
f = new File('/tmp/it/aint/there')
assert !f.exists()
assert !f.parentFile.exists()
f.parentFile.mkdirs() // XXX create the dirs "to the file"
assert f.parentFile.exists()
f.withWriter{ it << 'x' }
assert f.exists()
assert f.text=='x'
```